# Elasticsearch reindex api deleting document after copy

Tags: elasticsearch

I've gone through the _reindex api documentation a few times, and can't figure out if it's possible or not.  Once the document is copied from the source index to the destination index, is it possible to also remove the source document?

Here is the current _reindex api call body that I'm invoking:

```
{
  "source": {
    "index": "srcindex",
    "type": "type",
    "query": {
      "range": {
        "date": {
          "from": <timestamp>
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "dstindex",
    "type": "type"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, It is not supported i.e copying then deleting immediately(effectively `moving a document`).

You can find good discussion happened on this topic [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17998).

Eventually, you need to do `_reindex` then `_delete_by_query` to achieve your goal.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to be sure that I wasn't missing something.